# How to implement Clash readNew metastability workaround?

Tags: clash

How do I correctly use [`readNew`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/clash-prelude-0.99.3/docs/Clash-Prelude.html#g:7)?

A minimal example with two modules which just reads and writes an [`asyncRam`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/clash-prelude-0.99.3/docs/Clash-Prelude.html#g:4):

TopLevel.hs

```
module TopLevel where

import Clash.Prelude
import LowerLevel

topEntity 
  :: Clock System Source
  -> Reset System Asynchronous
  -> Signal System (Unsigned 5)
  -> Signal System (Maybe (Unsigned 5, BitVector 5))
  -> Signal System (BitVector 5)
topEntity = exposeClockReset topLevel

topLevel :: HiddenClockReset dom gated sync
         => Signal dom (Unsigned 5)
         -> Signal dom (Maybe (Unsigned 5, BitVector 5))
         -> Signal dom (BitVector 5)
topLevel rdAddr wrM = lowerLevel rdAddr wrM
```

LowerLevel.hs

```
module LowerLevel where

import Clash.Prelude

lowerLevel :: HiddenClockReset dom gated sync
           => Signal dom (Unsigned 5)
           -> Signal dom (Maybe (Unsigned 5, BitVector 5))
           -> Signal dom (BitVector 5)
lowerLevel rdAddr wrM = readNew (asyncRam d32) rdAddr wrM
```

Currently, when I compile this code I receive metastability warnings (though it is successful):

```
Compiling: TopLevel.topEntity LowerLevel.$sreadNew20998 (::
GHC.Classes.IP   rst   (Clash.Signal.Internal.Reset
     (Clash.Signal.Internal.Dom system 10000)
     Clash.Signal.Internal.Asynchronous)
-> GHC.Classes.IP
     clk
     (Clash.Signal.Internal.Clock
        (Clash.Signal.Internal.Dom system 10000)
        Clash.Signal.Internal.Source)
-> Clash.Signal.Internal.Clock
     (Clash.Signal.Internal.Dom system 10000)
     Clash.Signal.Internal.Source
-> Clash.Signal.Internal.Signal
     (Clash.Signal.Internal.Dom system 10000)
     (Clash.Sized.Internal.Unsigned.Unsigned 5)
-> Clash.Signal.Internal.Signal
     (Clash.Signal.Internal.Dom system 10000)
     (GHC.Base.Maybe
        (GHC.Tuple.(,)
           (Clash.Sized.Internal.Unsigned.Unsigned 5)
           (Clash.Sized.Internal.BitVector.BitVector 5)))
-> Clash.Sized.Internal.BitVector.BitVector 5) has potentially dangerous meta-stability issues:

The following clocks:
* GHC.Classes.IP   clk   (Clash.Signal.Internal.Clock
     (Clash.Signal.Internal.Dom system 10000)
     Clash.Signal.Internal.Source)
* Clash.Signal.Internal.Clock   (Clash.Signal.Internal.Dom system 10000)   Clash.Signal.Internal.Source belong to the same clock domain
and should be connected to the same clock source in order to prevent
meta-stability issues.
```

I've done some research and found this google group [answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/clash-language/readNew%7Csort:date/clash-language/gaBODE5368g/B_5SurAbAwAJ). I'm pretty sure this is **what** I should do, but I am not sure **how** to implement.

How would I inline `asyncRam clk d32` as mentioned in the post? How do I get the "free clk"? I was experimenting with the [`readNew`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/clash-prelude-0.99.3/docs/Clash-Explicit-Prelude.html#v:readNew) from [Clash.Explicit.Prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/clash-prelude-0.99.3/docs/Clash-Explicit-Prelude.html) (unsuccessfully), but I don't understand why I can't just use the [Prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/clash-prelude-0.99.3/docs/Clash-Prelude.html) version. I figure there might be some need to [`exposeClockReset`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/clash-prelude-0.99.3/docs/Clash-Signal.html#v:exposeClockReset) but from what I've read it seems like there's two clocks from the same domain being used to circumvent the metastability warnings? Please clarify, thanks!

**Update**: This is a known [issue](https://github.com/clash-lang/clash-compiler/issues/416). I am told it is fine to ignore the compiler warnings for now.